# Match two dataframes on multiple criteria within range of values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, range, match, criteria

I need some tips/clues on how it would be possible to match two dataframes in Python on multiple criteria that some of them are looking for values within range. The example:

1.First dataframe is a contract where we have locations from country, from postal code low, from postal code high, to country, to postal code low, to postal code high, contract ID.

```
from country from postal code low from postal code high to country to postal code low to postal code high ID
SE         0         19999            DE      90000         99999   ID1
SE     20000         29999            DE      90000         99999   ID2
SE     30000         39999            DE      90000         99999   ID3
SE     40000         49999            DE      90000         99999   ID4
SE     41250         41250            DE      90000         99999   ID5
```

2.Second dataframe is statistics file with exact postal code from and to and I need to find all unique matches from the first database:

```
From country  from postal code    to country  To postal code   ID (that should be the result):
SE              21789              DE          91000            ID2
SE              41250              DE          91000            ID4, ID5
```

In excel it could be done by Index and Match and array function, since both dataframes involves tens or even hundred of thousands rows, doing it in excel is not the optimal option, so looking to Python solution. I am a beginner in Python so at least a clue on what should I look into would be helpful. I know pandas merge function, but it requires exact match of columns, is it pandassql that could help, but I am not sure how can I refer to another DB as criteria for Where postal code <= postal code low & postal code >= postal code high?

Any tips?

Visualization of df:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand how you want to match, can you post the output of those two sample dfs?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of `pandas.merge_asof()`.

Comment: In the second file I would like to get contracts ID (ex. of the result is last column in second df). It means that if I have statistics of shipment from postal code 21000 in SE to postal code 91000 in DE, when correct contract ID is no 2 - there from country is SE, to country DE, from postal range from 20000 to 29999, to postal range is from 90000 to 99999, rules:
from country == from country & from postal code >= from postal code low & from postal code <= from postal code high & to country==to country & to postal code >=to postal code low & to postal code <=to postal code high.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to do a nested list comprehension:

```
df2["ID"] = [[idx for lo, hi, idx in zip(df["from postal code low"],
                                         df["from postal code high"],
                                         df["ID"]) if i in range(lo, hi+1)]
             for i in df2["from postal code"]]

print (df2)

  From country  from postal code to country  To postal code          ID
0           SE             21789         DE           91000       [ID2]
1           SE             41250         DE           91000  [ID4, ID5]
```

Comment: great! it works with this scale example, so now I am googling nested list comprehension to understand on how to connect other criterias, like df1["From country"] == df2["From country"] and df1["To country"] == df2["to country"] and same loop for "to postal code".

Comment: my wild guess didn't work: 
stats["ID"] = [[idx for lo, hi, tlo, thi, fc, tc idx in zip(contract["from postal code low"],
                contract["from postal code high"], contract["to postal code low"], contract["to postal code high"], 
                contract["from country"], contract["to country"],
                contract["ID"]) if i in range(lo, hi+1) and j in range (tlo, thi+1) and l==fc and k==tc]
             for i, j, l, k in stats[["from postal code", "to postal code", "From", "to"]]]

print (stats)

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to directly iterate though all options, in this case added range cols for a shorter if syntax at the loop:

```
contract_df['from_range'] = [range(t[0], t[1]) for t in zip(contract_df['from_postal_code_low'], contract_df['from_postal_code_high']+1)]
contract_df['to_range'] = [range(t[0], t[1]) for t in zip(contract_df['to_postal_code_low'], contract_df['to_postal_code_high']+1)]

lol = []
for r in stat_df.iterrows():
    l = []
    for r1 in contract_df.iterrows():
        if (r[1]['from_country'] == r1[1]['from_country']) and (r[1]['to_country'] == r1[1]['to_country']) and (r[1]['from_postal_code'] in r1[1]['from_range']) and (r[1]['to_postal_code'] in r1[1]['to_range']):
            l.append(r1[1]['ID'])
    lol.append(l)

stat_df['ID'] = lol
```

Comment: Thank you! But I get the error: the beginning of it:  in get_value(self, series, key)
   4409             try:
-> 4410                 return libindex.get_value_at(s, key)
   4411             except IndexError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.get_value_at()

Comment: does this error occur on a big dataset? if that's the case try tunning on first 20 rows or so. if that works try finding the problematic row

Comment: appearantly I made had column name "to" in the file I tested and it gave error, but after renaming, the code works! thank you very much!